# Server Error in '/' Application. An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Initially my project was running fine.

Suddenly got the following error

```
"Server Error in '/' Application.An item with the same key has already been added. ".
```

In this case the page is not submitted to the controller.I didn't use any dictionaries.

Comment: Perhaps try to get more info and post it, like a stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This generally happens when you are trying to post some data to server and the form data has multiple properties with the same name. Like you can have two input elements with same name or you are passing a JSON data which has same property name repeated. When you post the data, it hits the MVC default model binder (framework logic) which extracts all the values posted from the request and adds to a dictionary, and that's when it throws an error saying the same key is already added. So make sure the data submitted does not contain multiple property with same name. You can see what request are being sent to server from the browser developer window's network tab.